# GGplot 2 output is blank

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using the tidy text guide to text mining and changing to code to use on my own data.

I am at the stage of plotting the most frequent words in my data set.  I've already managed to get them into a data frame.

I've tried changing some parts of the code but this doesn't help as I'm not totally sure what each bit does.  I've looked everywhere online too and can't find an answer!

my data frame looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 1,343 x 2
   word            n
   <chr>       <int>
 1 reminders     104
 2 check         100
 3 checks        100
 4 mot            87
 5 car            82
 6 vehicle        79
 7 send           78
 8 people         73
 9 maintenance    44
10 vehicles       42
```

and the code to plot the most frequent word looks like this:

```
library (ggplot2)

frequentwordsstop  %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n > 40) %>% 
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(word, n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab (NULL) +
  coord_flip()
```

What I get is a blank square with 'n' on the x axis label. And that's it!

I don't get any error messages.  What I get is a blank square with 'n' on the x axis label. And that's it!

Comment: I get the expected plot when I use a non-tidyverse approach to this. If the tibble you posted is `frequentwordsstop`, wouldn't `count(word, sort = TRUE)` count each word once and set the count to 1? Another thing might be that an unintended package namespace might be overwriting the `reorder()` function (do you see multiple options appearing when you use `?reorder`?)

Comment: Hi, I've tried using ?reorder and it comes up with help documentation describing that reorder is a generic function (this is in RStudio).  So I don't think there's something else overwriting it.

I thought that count(word, sort = TRUE) was sorting the frequency of words so that e.g. I'd get a bar chart with the most frequent word first (reminders), then the second, (check) etc.

Would you be able to copy past what the non-tidyverse approach to this would be as perhaps that would help me?

Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data that looks like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~word, ~n,
              "reminders",     104,
              "check",         100,
              "checks",        100,
              "mot",            87,
              "car",            82,
              "vehicle",        79,
              "send",           78,
              "people",         73,
              "maintenance",    44,
              "vehicles",       42)

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    word            n
#>    <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 reminders     104
#>  2 check         100
#>  3 checks        100
#>  4 mot            87
#>  5 car            82
#>  6 vehicle        79
#>  7 send           78
#>  8 people         73
#>  9 maintenance    44
#> 10 vehicles       42
```

Then you have already counted it; the word counts are stored in the `n` column. You don't need to use `count()` again, and in fact, you'll get a nonsensical result if you try, which it sounds like you have experienced!

Since you already have counted your word frequencies, you can just pipe your results straight into the rest of that code you have for making the plot you are interested in.

```r
df %>%
  filter(n > 40) %>% 
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(word, n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab (NULL) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been able to generate the plot in a non-tidyverse fashion and I'll post this as an answer so I can include the plot and can have code-blocks. This is not intended as an actual answer.

```
# Loading in your data
z <- " 1 reminders     104
 2 check         100
 3 checks        100
 4 mot            87
 5 car            82
 6 vehicle        79
 7 send           78
 8 people         73
 9 maintenance    44
10 vehicles       42"
df <- read.table(text = z)[,-1] # Drop rownumbers

# Fix names
colnames(df) <- c("word", "n")

# Reorder factor
df$word <- factor(df$word, levels = df$word[order(df$n)])

ggplot(df, aes(word, n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Your reproduction doesn’t perform any of the data transformation that OP is doing; and that’s the reason it works, regardless of tidyverse use, because OP’s transformation is redundant, as your comment correctly observes.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, as I don't have OP's untransformed data. I'm not trying to imply that tidyverse use is bad, I'm just not fluent in its use myself.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I still don't understand the word sort TRUE thing as I've copied it from the tidyverse code and I'd thought it ordered the data from most frequently used word to the least.  However seeing your non-tidyverse method was very useful as I used that instead!  Thank you.